# Java fill an array with non duplicate records

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int i=0;
int nr = sc.nextInt();

int[] arr=new int[5];
while (i<arr.length || arr[i] < 11 ){
    System.out.println("Enter "+i+" index of array: ");
    int j = 0;
    if (arr[i]==arr[j]) {
        arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

How can I insert into an array only those values that are not repeated twice and the value should not pass 11,or else ask the user again.Please help,Stuck!

Comment: you should be using searching technique in order to ensure that value is not present in the array. where as the other part should be like `if(arr[i] > 11) then skip`.

Comment: Using array, you have [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)). For unicity, you can use a `Map` too. But I don't believe this would be needed for 5 item... you can iterate yourself each time ;)

Comment: Can anybody help me with a working code thank you!

Comment: Well, you could try first to create a not working code reading the array each time to find the value. This is not complicated so it is best if you try by yourself, this is obviously for training purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[5];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length;) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number less than 11.");
        Integer i = sc.nextInt();
        if (i < 11 && !Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(a -> a == i)) {
            arr[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("type 1 for ascending and 2 for descending order");
    int choice = sc.nextInt();
    if (choice == 1)
        Arrays.sort(arr);
    else if (choice == 2)
        Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

This code does work, but the search for an existing element is most probably an overkill for 5 elements, but useful if it scales up. Also note that this code does not work in Java 7. If you need some clarification on what the code does, just ask.

EDIT:
Code updated to offer sort choice

Comment: I've already marked your as an answer but let me ask one last question,how can I sort this asc,desc?or can you give me some indications?

Comment: you mean on output or at total?

Comment: the output after the check,after it has removed the duplicates ask the user  how to sort it

Comment: wait,the sort method says its not applicable for the sort(int[])

Comment: @User2333 where exactly does sai it? did you copy the whole code?

Comment: its okay I found another method

Comment: how to limit the entered number into 5,and then remove the duplicates

Comment: you can limit the maximum entries in this line `Integer[] arr = new Integer[5];` with the current code, you directly ignore duplicate entries. you could also make an output for the case the number is bigger than 10

Comment: at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(Unknown Source) throws this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153367/discussion-between-xtremebaumer-and-user2333).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code: You can change the size of the array from 3 and experiment with the code.

If you have any doubts then you are welcome to ask.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr = new int[3];
        int counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number less than 11.");
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            if (i < 11 && notFound(i, arr)) {
                arr[counter] = i;
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter == arr.length)
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    private static boolean notFound(int num, int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (num == arr[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i am asking to insert into the array if they are not dupicates

Comment: This program is doing the same if you will insert a value which is greater than 11 or if it already present in the array then it will not insert that value in the array else it will insert, this was only your requirement according to my understanding.